# Sending notification mail on saving page

Tags: php, laravel, email, notifications

I am using a Laravel based CRUD application. I need to send a notification mail to a specific mail address everytime I click the save button.

Could you please show me the way to start

Regards

Comment: Please start reading [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the SO rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good, well formed and on-topic question.

Comment: @gp_sflover You are right. I am sorry. I better ask question after I start the project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best options is to use [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) create an account and get smtp username and password get those info and paste them in `.env` file on laravel project, also don't forget to set up `MAIL_HOST` to mailtrap.io on `.env` file

Then use `Mail` namespace on the project controller and run the command `php artisan make:mail` so u create the `welcome.php` mail class, on your method that checks for the request to be submitted (in your case button) go ahead and send the mail `\Mail::to($user)->send(new welcome);`.

Note: on the welcome.php file stored  on `App\Mail\Welcome.php` you will have a build function that runs every time you call the class. That function basically returns a mail view which is stored on your view's folder (you can modify the email view as you want).

PS basic start.